# How to Calculate Derived rate and order user passed on it using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to calculate the user avarage rate from all the comments related to his profile and print it in his profile page , also in a category page for all users i want to calculate the rate and print it and order the users Descending passed on the avrage rating value .

my schema is :

```
UserAccount (id, category_id, name, description, IMGlogo, video)
Comment (id, User_id, name, body, email, date, **rating**)
```

how ?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information ?

Comment: Please include what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS average_rating
  FROM Comment
 WHERE User_id = ?;

SELECT ua.id, ua.name, AVG(c.rating) AS average_rating
  FROM UserAccount ua
  JOIN Comment c ON c.User_id = ua.id
 WHERE ua.category_id = ?
 GROUP BY ua.id
 ORDER BY average_rating DESC;
```